# Uniform continiuity vs. Continuity / cts. vs. not everywhere differentiable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Can something be uniformly continuous and not continuous.

Also for a function to be cts. and not everywhere differentiable. 
The only thing I can think of is the Weierstrass function.
And how does it look exactly. 
Are there any easier examples?

Answer (score 1):

Uniform continuity implies continuity. This easily follows from the definition.

An example of a continuous function that is not differentiable everywhere is $f(x)= |x|$. It is not differentiable at $0$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) has a nice diagram of the Weierstrass function.

Comment: Also, an example of a function that is continuous, but not uniformly so, is $f(x) = 1 / x$ for $0 < x$.

Comment: and differentiability implies continuity ?
So if f(x)= x^2 + 6x is differentiable, yes. 
Then it must also be continuous?

Comment: @Lilly'16 Differentiability "at a point" implies continuity at "that point". $|x|$ is continuous everywhere, but it is not differentiable at $0$. But for $x\neq 0$ it is differentiable, and therefore it must be continuous for $x\neq 0$. $|x|$ is continuous at $0$, but that's not because it is differentiable there.